# Laravel with Google BigQuery

Tags: laravel, google-bigquery

I'm working on an application in which I want to use both Laravel and Google BigQuery to store the data.

I want to continue to use Laravel's Eloquent models for easily generating SQL, but I want all the SQL to be sent to Google BigQuery for storing and reading the data.

Is this possible with Laravel?

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Failing to find a library that is already handling this ( You would want something similar to Laravel Scout ) - You could Write a wrapper around the Google BigQuery Service ( with something like this https://github.com/schulzefelix/laravel-bigquery there is other packages available as well ) - With this you would then need to look at writing events off of the Laravel model you want to send to BigQuery https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events if you want to listen for many different events on a given model i would look into using Observers - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers

I would start with the above & have a look at https://github.com/laravel/scout for ideas on how you might be able to implement this.

I'm sure the OSS community would be very thankful if you where to package it up as well.

Good luck!